# Printing 64-bit decimal numbers in freestanding environment

Tags: c, formatting, integer, embedded, gcc

I need to print signed 64-bit numbers in decimal form. Program runs in freestanding environment (no C library available, libgcc may be unavailable too, or may not work correctly). So I can't use printf(3) function.

I'am trying to write function, which will be able to convert number from binary form (int64_t) to ascii. Simple solution is to divide number by 10, and use remainder as next digit (from left to right, iteratively).

Unfortunately, processor doesn't have 64 bit division, and I can't rely on libgcc in that (__udivdi3 function). So I invented other way to perform binary->decimal conversion, by using binary coded decimal (BCD) numbers. First I convert binary number to BCD form (bit by bit, need 64 iterations, and need to sum BCD numbers), then convert BCD to ASCII.

Source code is following:

```
/*static*/ void _print_dec(intmax_t num)
{
    char *p;
    char buf[24 /* > log10(2^64) */];
    uint_fast8_t r;
    uint64_t n = num < 0 ? -num : +num;

    uint_fast16_t result_h = 0, digit_h = 0;
    uint64_t result = 0, digit = 1;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        /* sum bcd numbers: r = a + b, where r should be L-value  */
        #define BCD_ADD(type, r, a, b) do { \
            type t1 = a + (type)(0x6666666666666666 & ((type)-1 >> 4)), t2 = t1 ^ b; \
            t1 += b, t2 = ~(t1 ^ t2) & (type)0x1111111111111110; r = t1 - (t2>>2 | t2>>3); \
        } while (0);

        /* this macro computes rh:rl = ah:al + bh:bl (sum of compound BCD number), rh:rl should be L-value */
        #define BCD_ADD_COMPOUND(type_h, type, rh, rl, ah, al, bh, bl) do { \
            uint_fast8_t c = 0; \
            type t1 = al, t2 = bl; \
            BCD_ADD(type, rl, al, bl); \
            c = rl >> (sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT-4); \
            BCD_ADD(type_h, rh, ah, bh); \
            if (c >= 10 || (rl < t1 && rl < t2)) { \
                rl = (rl & ((type)-1 >> 4)) | ((c - 10ULL) << (sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT-4)); \
                BCD_ADD(type_h, rh, rh, 1); \
            } \
        } while (0)

        if (n & 1)
            BCD_ADD_COMPOUND(uint_fast16_t, uint64_t, result_h, result, result_h, result, digit_h, digit);

        BCD_ADD_COMPOUND(uint_fast16_t, uint64_t, digit_h, digit, digit_h, digit, digit_h, digit);
        n >>= 1;
    }

    p = &buf[sizeof(buf) - 1];
    *p = 0;
    do {
        r = result & 0x0f;
        *--p = r + '0';
        result = (result >> 4) | ((uint64_t)(result_h & 0x0f) << (sizeof(uint64_t)*CHAR_BIT-4));
        result_h = result_h >> 4;

    } while (result_h != 0 || result != 0);

    if (num < 0) *--p = '-';
    print_cstr(p);
}
#define print_dec(num) DECL_FUNC(_print_dec, num)
```

I hope, that somebody suggests me some improvements...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Code Review! Does this code work correctly? Your question is a little unclear in that regard. Also, it would be nice of you to expand your code into a minimal verifiable example, i.e. a small program that can be compiled and tested by us to make sure your code actually compiles and works.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I print 64-bit decimal numbers in freestanding environment?
>   suggests me some improvements...

**Create test cases**

Post lacks a good way to assess its correctness.  Since the goal is to *print* rather than form a *string*, that is later printed, (a better function IMO), we will do things the simply, but a bit the hard way and visually compare output.

Test case code

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_uint64_dec(uint64_t u) {
  if (u >= 10) {
    uint64_t udiv10 = u/10;
    u %= 10;
    print_uint64_dec(udiv10);
  }
  putchar((int)u + '0');
}

void print_int64_dec(int64_t i) {
  uint64_t u = (uint64_t) i;
  if (i < 0) {
    putchar('-');
    u = -u;
  }
  print_uint64_dec(u);
}

int main(void) {
  int64_t ia[] = {INT64_MIN + 1, 0, 10, INT64_MAX/2, INT64_MAX - 1};
  for (size_t index = 0; index< sizeof ia/sizeof ia[0]; index++) {
    int64_t i = ia[index];
    print_int64_dec(i-1); putchar('\n');
    print_int64_dec(i+0); putchar('\n');
    print_int64_dec(i+1); putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

And its output:

```
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775806
-1
0
1
9
10
11
4611686018427387902
4611686018427387903
4611686018427387904
9223372036854775805
9223372036854775806
9223372036854775807
```

OP code produced the same results.

---

**Plan for the future**

"processor doesn't have 64 bit division, and I can't rely on libgcc" --> accepting this as a given, this curious restriction could easily be removed later.  To that end, recommend to encapsulate this specialized code - **and only the specialized part needed** - the divide and mod of a `int64_t`, without the print part.

Something like

```
static unsigned mod10(uint64_t *u) {
  uint64_t dividend = *u;
  uint64_t quo = 0;
  uint64_t div = 0xA000000000000000; //largest shifted 10
  while (div >= 10) {
    quo <<= 1; // quo *= 2;
    if (dividend >= div) {
      dividend -= div;
      quo++;
    }
    div >>= 1;
  }
  *u = quo;
  return (unsigned) dividend;
}

void print_uint64_dec(uint64_t u) {
  if (u >= 10) {
    #if CURIOUS_CODE_NEEDED
      uint64_t udiv10 = u;
      u = mod10(&udiv10);
    #else
      uint64_t udiv10 = u/10;
      u %= 10;
    #endif
    print_uint64_dec(udiv10);
  }
  putchar((int)u + '0');
}
```

---

**Simplify**

I just had too much trouble following the "invented other way".  I recommend to  re-write to **only replace** the missing /10, mod 10 functionality in  a stand-alone function.  When a target platform lacks standard functionality, do not entangle your fill-in-the-gap code with the rest of user code.  Keep them separate.

---

**Minor - Use consistent types**

Code   converts `intmax_t` to `uint64_t` as if  `intmax_t` is always a 64-bit type.  `(u)intmax_t` is at least a 64-bit type.  Choose `(u)intmax_t` or `(u)int64_t`.

**Minor - Avoid UB**

`intmax_t num ... -num` is UB when `num == INTMAX_MIN`.  Simply enough to fix. Negate an *unsigned* type

```
// uint64_t n = num < 0 ? -num : +num;
uint64_t n = num;
if (num < 0) n = -n;
// OR
uint64_t n = num < 0 ? -(uintmax_t)num : num;
// Or various other approaches.
```

**Minor - Missing  headers**

I needed the below to compile your code.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
```